# Calculating simple math operations at runtime rust (+,-,*,/,%,**)

Tags: rust

I want to make calculations based on the user input. it is already parsed into this structure:

```rs
enum ParsedToken {
    Number(f64),
    Operator(Action),
}

#[derive(Debug)]
enum Action {
    /// +
    Plus,
    /// -
    Sub,
    /// *
    Mul,
    /// /
    Div,
    /// %
    Mod,
    /// **
    Exp,
    /// (
    BracketOpen,
    /// )
    BracketClose,
}
```

is there wasy way to make the calculations? a possibility is to use js_sandbox, but I don't really like that. could I somehow use rusts math implementation. Is there an easy way to do that, without sorting the math operations, recursively calculating each ()?

Comment: This is not really Rust specific, but I would look into how parsers work. You would at least need something like a stack and a structure to process binary operations etc. This is not really trivial, but your approach will not suffice.